# How to delete any occurrences of a string from another string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I delete any occurrence of a string from another string?

Ex:

Input: `String1 = "himynamemomoohi"
      String 2 = "moo"`

Output:`himynamehi`

I was thinking of using if statements like:

```
if string 2 in string 1:
     #remove string 2
```

But that doesnt work because it would only remove moo and not mo, which is also a part of moo. Hope Im being clear on what im trying to say.

To clarify: `String 1 = hihihiiiigrassgrahiii
           String 2 = grass`

Output: `hihihiiihiii`

It should remove grass and gra because gra is part of grass.

The output should be such that it only deletes the occurrences of the word starting from the very top. For example, if the string is moohimotoo, and you want to remove moo, you should remove moo and mo from the string. You should not remove oo (too) because it does not start from the very beginning of the string.

Comment: For the first, you'd want all `m`s removed as well?

Comment: Why should it remove `mo` if the full substring is `moo`? In that case should it remove any instance of `m` and `o` as well?

Comment: I guess it should be that it has to be more than 1 character following the same order as the string.

Comment: Would that mean `hool` should return `hl` for `moo`? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Please be sure what you want. Nobody can help you without you knowing what the desired result is

Comment: If you're wanting to remove any instance of those letters in string two from string one, you can:

Comment: Argh hard to do this with mobile phone. One sec

Comment: Seems like depending on the order that the *partial strings* are removed, you can get different results - for `hihihiiiigrassgrahiii` if `gr` is removed first you get a different result than if you remove `gra` or `gras` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what You want to achieve:

```
import re
s1 = 'hihihiiiigrassgrahiii'
s2 = 'grass'
for i in reversed(range(1,len(s2))):
    s1 = re.sub(s2[:i+1], "", s1)
print(s1)
hihihiiiihiii
```

The loop removes sequentially strings:

```
grass
gras
gra
gr
```

from `s1` string.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a regular expression:

```
import re

s1 = 'hihihiiiigrassgrahiii'
s2 = 'grass'

re.sub('|'.join([s2[:i] for i in range(len(s2), 1, -1)]), '', s1)
```

output:

```
'hihihiiiiassahiii'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String1= "himynamemomoohi"
String2="mo"
Res=[]
A=String2.split()
R=String1.split()
For x in R:
    If A[0] or A[1] not in x:
        Res.append(x)
String1=str(Res)
print(String1)
```

Comment: Thank you but could you specify what "Res" is?

Comment: Ah crap. Forgot to initialize Res. It's an array to hold the new characters. The res array should contain just the letters not included in string2

Comment: Edited. Should be good to go

Answer (score 2):

Construct a regex pattern that contains all partial length strings and substitute.

```
import re
def pattern(s):
    if len(s)==2:
        return s
    return s + '|' + pattern(s[:-1])

s = "himynamemomoohi"
t = "moo"
print(re.sub(pattern(t),'',s))
print(re.sub(pattern('grass'),'','hihihiiiigrassgrahiii'))
```

It will only parse the test string once and remove all non-overlapping matches. If once a substring is removed the new string contains another match because the sequence has *collapsed* it won't find those - for example if string being *tested* is `'himynamemmomooohi'`.

If the final string cannot contain any of the substrings, you would have to substitute in an iteration: something like.

```
def g(s,t):
    rex = re.compile(pattern(t))
    while True:
        u = rex.sub('',s)
        if u == s:
            break
        s = u
    return u

print(g('himynamemmomooohi','moo'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It will **remove any substring occurrences** of `string_2` from `string_1`.

```
if string_2 in string_1:
     string_1.replace(string_2, '')
```

Example with your string values

```
>>string_1 = 'hihihiiiigrassgrahiii'
>>string_2 = 'grass'
>>if string_2 in string_1:
>>    string_1.replace(string_2,'')
>>
>>print(string_1)
>>'hihihiiiigrahiii'
```

Note: If you want to **remove all characters** of `string_2` from `string_1`, then do the following

```
for letter in string_2:
    string_1.replace(letter,'')
```

Example with your string values

```
>>string_1 = 'hihihiiiigrassgrahiii'
>>string_2 = 'grass'
>>for letter in string_2:
>>    string_1.replace(letter,'')
>>
>>print(string_1)
>>'hihihiiiihiii'
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way I can remove the "gra" from hihihiiigrahiii as gra is in grass as well?

Comment: @Eren145 I updated it :)
The last part should do what you want.

Comment: Nice and simple :)